# django modelformset create one object

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating an app that allows anonymous input of data, and have condensed my difficulties down to a simple Author example.

My problem is that each time I input a new author, the number of forms rendered after Submit is increased by N+1 author. (ie the first time used, there is 1 form, then 2, then 3). I only want one blank form to be displayed, and then will later use other apps to retrieve the data.

It seems there could be two ways to solve the problem. 1) Get formset.management_form to return the last form (eg slicing: '{% for form in formset[-1] %}', which does not work. 2) To have view.py only send one new form instead of the formset in render_to_response() - how to do this?

---models.py---

```py
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

---/models.py---

---views.py---

```py
django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from author.models import Author , AuthorForm

def manage_authors(request):
    AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author)
    if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
    else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet()
    return render_to_response("manage_authors.html",{"formset": formset,})
```

---/views.py---

---manage_authors.html---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <table>
            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form }}
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </body>
</html>
```

---/manage_authors.html---

---urls.py---

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from author.views import manage_authors
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^author/$", manage_authors),
)
```

---/urls.py---

UPDATE:
Thanks for the suggestions to use modelform. The django docs had only shown template interactions with modelformset. Using:

---views.py---

```py
def manage_authors(request):
    form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = AuthorForm()
    return render_to_response("manage_authors.html",{"form": form,})
```

---/views.py

and only using the the tag {{ form }} in manage_authors.html, does what I need.

Comment: If you only want one blank form, why use a formset at all? Why not just a simple modelform?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`max_num` and `extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#limiting-the-number-of-editable-objects) fields while creating model formset as

```
AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, max_num=1, extra=1)
```

This will try to show at most 1 form, if there isn't any existing.

However, you may want to think if you really have to use modelformset as *@Daniel Roseman* suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on how to use modelform with a template per your suggestions. When I try modelformset_factory(Author, max_num=1, extra=1), then I get the complement of what I want: I get all the previous records, but no blank entry. I want one blank.